# Need regex help in PHP 5

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Ok. Admittedly, I am not the best at working with regular expressions. What I am doing is a screen scrape, then trying to fix the img src values in the embedded images to point back to the original domain. This is the regex I have been trying variations of (too many to list - here's the current one):

```
preg_match_all('/<img\b[^>]*>/i', $html, $images);
```

What this ends up doing is to replace all `<` with `/>`. What I need it to do is just return the (currently) five images on the page in an array so that I can work with those to fix their src values, then write them back to $html, which is set at the beginning of the file:

```
$html = file_get_contents($target_url);
```

Comment: It seems like you're just trying to get the src attribute.  Will DomDocument or even simple xml not do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 5):

Basically, don't do this with regex.  You ***can*** parse HTML with regex, but it is almost certainly not worth the effort.

Do it with genuine DOM parsing instead, using the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) class:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $image->setAttribute('src', 'http://example.com/' . $image->getAttribute('src'));
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: And if you're familiar with jQuery you can try http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/